# Mapbox API - Regenerate a Tileset after it's related Dataset has been updated

Tags: mapbox, api

I'm using [Mapbox's API to update the features on a dataset](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#the-feature-object). However, I'm not seeing the changes automatically appear in the tileset that's been generated from it afterwards.

Is there an extra step that I need to trigger, via the API, to accomplish a tileset refresh from the updated dataset?

I can confirm that the dataset when viewed in Mapbox Studio does have the expected data changes present, but maps that use the related style which uses the related tileset still shows the old data.

I believe I need to find the API equivalent of "Update a connected tileset" that is available via Mapbox Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the API I needed was for "uploads":

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#uploads

Though I think the complex geometries I have on some of the features is causing problems updating the tileset anyway.